# Why does firebase push_token return Blacklisted?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am implementing Firebase messaging in my app.

While I am testing the app sends the refreshed_token to my database, but in live production environment (Play store) it returns 'BLACKLISTED' as push_token.

Does someone know why this happen? Or what I can do to fix this problem.
Can't find others with the same problem.

I use the code from the Firebase documentation.

```
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    super.onTokenRefresh();
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
    sendTokenToServer(refreshedToken);
}
```

The sendTokenToServer method posts the token to my api and inserts in the database.

Comment: We have the same problem. Any news about this strange behaviour?

Comment: @DreamOfMirrors No news :( , still experiencing the same problem.. Did you find a solution?

Comment: This just happened to me too, the only thing I can add is that this came from an Android device (My app runs on Android & iOS) and that I read somewhere (can't find where) that this may be related to the app being run on emulators.

Comment: @kR105 If it happens to be that emulators are blacklisted and when I look at my Firebase statistic I currently have 3 blacklisted devices in my database and 3 foreign country's registered in Firebase that are not related to my app. So these device can be emulators. Still not sure...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can conclude after researching this problem that when an emulator runs the app Firebase will return BLACKLISTED. Also thanks to @kR105

Comment: I saw this morning in my server log that a Nexus 5X sent me a BLACKLISTED token so it seems it can occur to a real device. Strange.

Comment: @2ndGAB are you sure it is not an emulated device? Or how can you be sure?

Comment: I cannot be sure at 100%, But that would be surprising that a developper uses my application webservices to make some tests.

Comment: I also have a Nexus 5X BLACKLISTED, I am not using an emulator.

Comment: @ken well, what is your explanation?

Comment: @sj0rske I expect for answer of this question as well

Comment: Same here, 5X blacklisted

Comment: same here Redmi pro 6 blacklisted.

Answer (score 13):

from Firebase support:

Hi there,

It seems that this is a known minor issue with our internal infrastructure where the device used for the Play Store review can be BLACKLISTED by GCM / FCM in some occasions. However, this should not affect your real users.
We are looking beyond Firebase and working with Play Store team to avoid this inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

The App will be running on an emulator hence Firebase token will be Blacklisted