# How to resolve Android FCM token:BLACKLISTED?

Tags: android

I have developed my app and have deployed it on my play-store, as my users install the app my FCM runs fine **but as I save the tokens to my server(remote server) I am getting some users tokens as BLACKLISTED in my mysql table or database**.

I have read the FCM documentation but they don't give a proper solution on how to reassign my users a usable token so that my blacklisted user receives my messages as well as I send to all my users.

How to do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42136122/why-does-firebase-push-token-return-blacklisted