# Xiaomi Mi 5X device returning Firebase Token as BLOCKLISTED

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, xiaomi

All sudden now my application returning `Firebase Token as BLACKLISTED`.

From long time my app is running on wide range of real devices like Android Custom OS & Android Standard OS.

But recently one of my users who using ***Xiaomi Mi 5x custom Android OS Version 8.1.0 and own UI called MIUI which is MIUI 11.0.3***. are getting `Firebase Token as BLACKLISTED`.

> Below is my code that how am generating Firebase Token:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance()
.getInstanceId()
.addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
                    String newToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();
                    prefUtils.setTokenDevice(newToken);
                }
            });
```

> Below is my manifest code:

```
<service
  android:name=".fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
  android:exported="false"
  android:stopWithTask="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
</service>
```

> Below is MyFirebaseMessagingService `onNewToken()` method

```
@Override
public void onNewToken(String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);
    PrefUtils prefUtils = new PrefUtils(getApplicationContext());
    prefUtils.setTokenDevice(s);
    Log.e("onNewToken", "onNewToken:: " + s);
}
```

I have gone through following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42136122) , but here as per the answers is saying it's due to application is running in `Emulators`. But my application is running in physical device. Could anyone please help me to solve the issue?

Thanks in advance.